# Concat arrays of objects

Tags: javascript

I have few arrays with objects and I need to merge them in to one, but next code doesn't works, it return empty array:

```js
let y = [{id:1, value: 'test1'}, {id:2, value: 'test2'}];
let z = [{id:3, value: 'test3'}, {id:4, value: 'test4'}];
let x = [{id:5, value: 'test5'}, {id:6, value: 'test6'}];
    
    
let arr = [];
    
arr.concat(...x,...y,...z);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: `let arr = [...y, ...x, ...z];`

Comment: `arr.concat` returns a *new array*…!? It does not modify `arr` in place.

Comment: `concat` creates a new array. Change it to `arr.push(...x,...y,...z)`

Answer (score 1):

[Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

> The `concat()` method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method does not change the existing arrays, but instead ***returns*** a new array

```js
let y = [{id:1, value: 'test1'}, {id:2, value: 'test2'}];
let z = [{id:3, value: 'test3'}, {id:4, value: 'test4'}];
let x = [{id:5, value: 'test5'}, {id:6, value: 'test6'}];


let arr = [].concat(...x,...y,...z);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Or just `[].concat(x,y,z)`